# Using <ul> instead of <input> in django templates

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-views

I am using a library [tagit](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown) and it uses `<ul>` and i'd like to use it to pass the tags to the views but when i try to use

```
<ul type="input" name='skills'>
```

instead of

```
<input type="input" name='skills'>
```

i get

```
MultiValueDictKeyError
```

so is there a way to use the ul as an input to the views !?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. `ul` is an 'unordered list' and you can't use it for input

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony if i don't use ul the plugin won't work, i am confused actually.